# How to bind to WPF ProgressBar's Visibility element?

Tags: wpf

How do I bind to WPF's ProgressBar Visibility element? I can't bind it to a string property as it takes an enum with three options: Collapsed, Visible and Hidden.
Please show understandable code for the bound visibility of ProgressBar. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<Grid Width="150" Margin="30,0" Visibility="{Binding ProgressBarVisibility}">
    <ProgressBar Width="150" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="#FF01D328"
                 Minimum="-3" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding DownloadPercentage, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <TextBlock Text="Downloading" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

And in the viewmodel:

```
public Visibility ProgressBarVisibility
{
    get
    {
        return (DownloadingPdf && DownloadPercentage < 100) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}

private int mDownloadPercentage;
public int DownloadPercentage
{
    get { return mDownloadPercentage; }
    set
    {
        if (mDownloadPercentage==value)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            mDownloadPercentage = Math.Min(Math.Abs(value), 100);
            OnPropertyChanged("DownloadPercentage");
            OnPropertyChanged("DownloadProgressBarVisibility");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) can u give me a code that binding the Value?.

Comment: Sure, I will edit the answer.